# App icons not showing for microsoft store apps when searching

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, microsoft-store

When I use Windows search to find programs installed through the Microsoft Store, their icons don't show up properly. Instead of their normal icons, their all replaced with the Paint3D icon. I did set Paint3D as the default program for some image formats, including .ico files but I have since changed it for that specific format. This issue affects both default programs like the clock or Microsoft store, as well as programs I've installed myself. However, apps that come pre-installed with Windows NOT through the Microsoft Store, like File Explorer or Command Prompt, don't have this problem, as well as any other normal programs downloaded from the web.

Comment: Not true here, Windows 10 and 11.  Try running DISM / DFC and see if the initial repairs fix the issue.   .........  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I would try resetting the `.ico` file association by using the registry key located [here](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-and-restore-default-apps-for-file-types-in-windows-11.2139/)

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Or what Ramhound suggested?

Comment: @John Sorry for the late reply, never done registry editing before so it took me a bit to figure out. I tried both but no luck, after both I restarted my PC but still didn't see any change. I also tried just completely deleting the .ico registry, restarting and then also remerging the new registry from your link and no change. Assuming my only option would be a full reinstall of windows, as I didn't have this problem originally, but I dont think this problem affects me enough to warrant going through all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Since DISM / SFC did not work, then next step is a Windows 10 Repair install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything. Keep Everything is just that, and is not a fresh instal.

The Keep Everything repair often works. If not, it normally means the User Profile is damaged or the operating system is seriously damaged.

In either case, the best solution is to back up and reinstall Windows.